# Does VS2010 not comply with "Evaluation of user-defined conversions" in C# 4.0 spec?

Tags: c#, syntax

If you compile the following code with Visual Studio 2010:

```
    public struct A
    {
        public static implicit operator B(A a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("11111111111");
            return new B();
        }
    }
    public struct B
    { }
    public static B F(A? a)
    {
        return (B)a;
    }
```

using ILSpy, `return (B)a;` is actually compiled as `return A.op_Implicit(a.value)`.

By my understanding of C# 4.0 chapter 6.4.5 'User-defined explicit conversions', it should produce a compiler error.

But, reading ECMA 334 chapter 13.4.4 'User-defined explicit conversions', it has a different rule which the above code seems to comply with.

C# 4.0:

> Find the set of applicable user-defined and lifted conversion
>   operators, U. This set consists of the **user-defined and lifted**
>   implicit or explicit conversion operators declared by the classes or
>   structs in D that convert from a type encompassing or encompassed by S
>   to a type encompassing or encompassed by T. If U is empty, the
>   conversion is undefined and a compile-time error occurs.

ECMA 334:

> Find the set of applicable conversion operators, U. This set consists
>   of the user-defined and, **if S and T are both nullable**, lifted implicit
>   or explicit conversion operators (§13.7.3) declared by the classes or
>   structs in D that convert from a type encompassing or encompassed by S
>   to a type encompassing or encompassed by T. If U is empty, there is no
>   conversion, and a compile-time error occurs.

Am I correct that VS2010 does not comply with the "Evaluation of user-defined conversions" section in the C# 4.0 spec, but does comply with the ECMA spec?

Comment: There is no sentence, including the title, which has a question mark in it. All you've done is make statements. Are we supposed to guess what your question is?

Comment: update title. please review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first see what should happen when we follow various rules.

Following the rules in the C# 4.0 spec:

- The set D of types to search for user-defined conversions consists of A and B.
- The set U of applicable conversions consists of the user-defined implicit conversion from A to B, and the lifted user-defined implicit conversion from A? to B?.
- We must now choose the unique best of those two elements of U.
- The most specific source type is A?.
- The most specific target type is B.
- U does not contain any conversion from A? to B, so this is ambiguous.

This should make sense. We do not know here whether the conversion should use the lifted conversion, converting from A? to B? and then from B? to B, or whether we should use the unlifted conversion, convert from A? to A and then A to B.

---

ASIDE:

Upon deeper reflection it is not clear that this is a difference which makes any difference.

Suppose we use the lifted conversion. If A? is non-null then we will convert from A? to A, then A to B, then B to B?, then B? back to B, which will succeed. If A? is null then we will convert from A? directly to a null B?, and then crash when unwrapping that to B.

Suppose we use the unlifted conversion and A? is non-null. Then we convert from A? to A, A to B, done. If A? is null then we crash when unwrapping A? to A.

So in this case both versions of the conversion have exactly the same action, so it doesn't really matter which we choose, and so calling this an ambiguity is unfortunate. However, this does not change the fact that **clearly the compiler is not following the letter of the C# 4 specification**.

---

What about the ECMA spec?

- The set U consists of the user-defined conversion from A to B, but not the lifted conversion because S (which is A?) and T (which is B) are not both nullable.

And now we have only one to choose from, so overload resolution has an easy job of it.

However, this does not imply that the compiler is following the rules of the ECMA spec.  **In fact it is following the rules of neither spec.** It is *closer* to the ECMA spec in that it does not add both operators to the candidate set, and therefore, in this simple case, chooses the only member of the candidate set.  But in fact it *never* adds the lifted operator to the candidate set, *even when both the source and target are nullable value types*. Moreover it violates the ECMA spec in numerous other ways that would be shown up by more complex examples:

- Lifted conversion semantics (that is, inserting a null check before calling the method and skipping it if the operand is null) are allowed on user-defined conversions from a non-nullable struct type to a nullable struct type, pointer type or reference type!  That is, if you have a conversion from A to string, then you get a lifted conversion from A? to string that produces a null string if the operand is null.  This rule is found nowhere in either spec.
- According to the spec, the types that must encompass or be encompassed by each other are the type of the expression being converted (called S in the specification) and the formal parameter type of the user-defined conversion. The C# compiler actually checks for encompassment of the *underlying* type of the expression being converted if it is a nullable value type. (S0 in the spec.) This means that certain conversions which ought to be rejected are instead accepted.
- According to the spec, the best target type should be determined by looking at the set of output types of the various conversions, lifted or unlifted. A user-defined conversion from A to B should be treated as having an output type of B for the purposes of finding the best output type. But if you had a cast from A to B? then the compiler would actually consider B? as the output type of the *unlifted* conversion for the purposes of determining the most specific output type!

I could go on (and on and on...) for hours about these and numerous other bugs in user-defined conversion processing. We've barely scratched the surface here; we haven't even gotten into what happens when generics get involved. But I will spare you. The takeaway here is: you cannot narrowly parse any version of the C# specification and from it determine what will happen in a complicated user-defined conversion scenario. The compiler *usually does what the user expects*, and usually does it for the wrong reasons.

This is both one of the most complicated parts of the specification, and the part of the specification that the compiler complies with the least, which is a bad combination. This is deeply unfortunate.

I made a valiant attempt to bring Roslyn into compliance with the specification but I failed; doing so introduced far, far too many real-world breaking changes. Instead I made Roslyn copy the behavior of the original compiler, just with a much cleaner, easier-to-understand implementation.

Comment: What would you think of the idea of allowing type members and conversion operators to indicate via attributes what sorts of transformations should be allowable on them? Language designers seem to work hard formulating rules to discriminate between cases where a transform will make sense and those where it will generate silly code; letting programmers mark members where transforms would generate silly code (so they shouldn't compile) and those where they might seem silly but would actually work (and thus should compile) would ease the need to have rules identify all the tough cases.

Comment: @supercat: To be frank I think the fact that there are representation-changing conversions at all is an indication of a design failure. User-defined conversions (and other operators) seem to exist primarily to mitigate the shortcomings of arithmetic in C, which is pretty horrid. C# improves upon a bad situation but doesn't really solve the problem: computers are supposedly good at math and yet we give you fourteen built-in types none of which can actually do integer arithmetic without introducing bizarre failure modes.

Comment: With regard to numerics, I think Java failed to consistently define what implicit or explicit conversions should mean, and .NET followed Java's lead rather than fixing the problem. If the allowable implicit promotions were [SByte|Byte]->[Int16|UInt16]->[Int32|UInt32]->[Int64|UInt64]->Decimal->Double->Single, then for any trio of types which were convertible T->U->V, one could define rounding rules such that converting a T to a U and then a V would be the same as converting a T directly to V. The rule for implicit conversion would not be...

Comment: ...whether the conversion from `T` to U` would yield a unique `U` for every `T`, but rather whether given the best representation in type `T` of some abstract numeric quantity, one can determine which `U` *best represents that quantity*.  If one knows that the best `Decimal` representation of some number is `123456789.5m`, that pretty well implies that the best `double` representation is `123456789.5` and the best `float` representation is `123456792.0f`. By contrast, knowing the best `float` representation of a number doesn't say what `double` represents it best.

Comment: Sorry I drifted a bit off topic; what I really meant to say is that I really dislike the use of cast syntax for floating-point to integer conversions (I think `.TruncInt32` `.FloorInt32`, and `RoundInt32` (and likewise `Int64`) methods would have been much better.  A statement `int foo = (int)2.6`;` can't really find the `int` that best describes the `double` 2.6, because *there isn't one*.  Neither 2 nor 3 could reasonably be considered a representation of any number for which `2.6` would be the best `double` representation.

Comment: @supercat: I'm not entirely with you on double going to float, but I certainly agree that the explicit float-to-int is just bad. Much better to, as you say, make the semantics of the conversion explicit in the code.

Comment: If a `16777216f` means "the exact numeric quantity 16777216", then implicit conversions from `float` to `double` would make sense, but from `int` to `float` would not (since `(float)16777217` would yield `16777216f`, and 16777217 isn't the exact quantity 16777216). If it represents a "fuzzy" quantity, then implicit conversion of any non-complex number to `float` makes sense, but from `float` to `double` doesn't. Having a universal implicit conversion `double`->`float` would cause some comparisons to behave oddly, but the fix for that would be to have an attribute...

Comment: ...that would allow things like the `==` overloads for `float` and `double` to specify that they should only be considered when their operands would not require implicit casting. I can think of at least three sensible meanings for `someLong == someDouble`, and the only one which I would consider justifiable without a typecast would require an explicit `(Int64,Double)` overload (confirm the `Double` has zero fractional part, fits the range of `Int64`, and after conversion equals the `Int64`). Otherwise, the programmer should have to convert the operands to compatible types before comparing.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for your answer. If C# team can provide the internal spec for C# compiler(not the C# 4.0 spec), then we can learn more.

Comment: @Vince: No need, Eric Lippert is the closest thing to a 4.0 C# walking spec. He was a lead programmer of the C# compiler and part of the design team of the C# language up to version 4.0. I don't think there is any internal C# spec different from the publicly available one anyways. What would be the point? It would only be confusing.

Comment: @EricLippert: Upon some further consideration, I think the inconsistent implicit-numeric-conversions behaviors of Java and .NET make a prime example of a situation where an unfortunate language-design decisions results from a desire to have the compiler select the "less surprising" transform in a case where either transform might make sense *but neither should have been allowed* (e.g. `someDouble == someFloat`). It would be good to have the `==` operator define an equivalence relation; when applied to a mix of `double` and `float`, it will only do so if mixed conversions are done as `double`.

Comment: @EricLippert: I would guess that fact was probably the driving force between disallowing implicit `double` to `float` conversions.  Even though the result of `(float)someDouble == someFloat` is often more meaningful than `someDouble == (double)someFloat`, I would readily accept that a `double` should not be implicitly converted to `float` *in a comparison*.  On the other hand, *a `float` shouldn't be implicitly converted to `double` there either*. Instead, the compiler should demand that operands be cast to matching types. If there could have been exceptions to normal type promotion rules...

Comment: ...the rules themselves could have then been designed around the more *generally*-benign cases where an implicit cast to `float` would yield a clear, unambiguous, and sensible result (e.g. `float foo = 0.1;`). It should be possible to have a method which can accept an arbitrary mix of `float` and `double` while keeping the extra precision of those values that have it, but that doesn't mean the compiler shouldn't squawk at `float one=1f,ten=10f; double foo = one/ten;`. Providing ways to let programmers *specify* what transforms to allow would be more helpful than trying to refine rules for it.

Comment: Since the compiler won't be changed to comply with the spec, will future versions of the spec be changed to match the compiler?